# Using or with Python Flask SQLAlchemy doesn't work

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've got a Flask app and I'm trying to get a SQLalchemy query using OR to return two different status like this but in one query:

```
        csv_list_1 = csvTable.query.filter_by(file_uuid=file_uuid).filter_by(status="Validated")

        csv_list_2 = csvTable.query.filter_by(file_uuid=file_uuid).filter_by(status="Also Validated")
```

I've found a couple of answers on stack overflow but trying the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
csv_list = csvTable.query.filter_by(file_uuid=file_uuid).filter_by(or_(status="Validated", status="Also Validated"))
```

I get:

> SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column names shouldn't be keyword arguments here, it should be a boolean check like this:

```
csv_list = csvTable.query.filter_by(file_uuid=file_uuid)\
    .filter(or_(status == "Validated", status == "Also Validated"))
```

Comment: TypeError: filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given is the new error.  I amended the link to remove the _by and just use filter csv_list = csvTable.query.filter_by(file_uuid=file_uuid)\
    .filter(or_(status == "Validated", status == "Also Validated")) and it works.  Thank you.  Can you update your answer and I will accept.

Comment: Thanks wpercy, was knocking my head against a wall then!